# Search outlook emails using powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have tried some commands on my exchange server looking for some emails in order to delete them later on but each command that I use is not executed and this error shows up

> Search-Mailbox : The term 'Search-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
>   a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

This is the command

```
New-ComplianceSearch -Name "Remove Phishing Message" -ExchangeLocation all -ContentMatchQuery 'subject:"Update your account information"'
```

Comment: i thot you had to either load the Exch cmdlets locally OR establish a session to the exchange server that has those cmdlets installed. have you done either of those?

Comment: I tried to execute these cmdlest locally on the Exch server.

Comment: Is there a module that I need to import?

Comment: it seems your question has been answered in very nice detail by RanadipDutta. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can run Exchange Powershell commands from a regular Powershell console, you need to do the following:

1. Install the Exchange Management Tools (if not already installed) from the Exchange installation media.
2. Import the Exchange module into your Powershell session based on your version. The commands are listed below:

   ```
   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin; #For Exchange 2007

   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010; #For #Exchange 2010

   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn; #For 2014 and 2016
   ```

Comment: Using Add-PSSnapin for the Exchange cmdlets is unsupported (and some cmdlets won't work as expected). The only proper way to load them is by creating a remote session to the exchange PS endpoint and importing it (which is very wel documented by Microsoft)

Comment: He only needs to get the mailbox user; for that why bother about support.

Comment: Like I said: some cmdlets won't work as expected (I found this out the "hard way", a lot of the Exchange cmdlets return no data when importing the snapin)

Comment: Send me the list separately with version details. When you talk about no data, you mean to say the cmdlets just gonna end up giving the control back to the console? If yes, then its not at all possible. I need to know the full details to verify if at all it is a bug or not.